# How do I link python 3.4.3 to opencv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

So I have OpenCV on my computer all sorted out, I can use it in C/C++ and the Python 2.7.* that came with my OS.

My computer runs on Linux Deepin and whilst I usually use OpenCV on C++, I need to use Python 3.4.3 for some OpenCV tasks.

Problem is, I've installed python 3.4.3 now but whenever I try to run an OpenCV program on it, it doesn't recognize numpy or cv2, the modules I need for OpenCV. I've already built and installed OpenCV and I'd rather not do it again

Is there some way I can link my new Python 3.4.3 environment to numpy and the opencv I already built so I can use OpenCV on Python 3.4.3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to install Opencv for Python 3.x again I guess.

Comment: I think Py2 and 3 have different OpenCV bindings?!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Download the OpenCV module
2. Copy the ./opencv/build/python/3.4/x64/cv2.pyd file
3. To the python installation directory path: ./Python34/Lib/site-packages.

I hope this helps